# How to iterate DBObject values in Java

Tags: java, string, mongodb

I have values that coming from MongoDB stored in a DBObject. and I needed to store that value in a set one by one. As being new to MongoDB I am not actually getting idea coherently how to proceed that.

> ```
>     String date = sdf.format(cal2.getTime());
>     List<String> dateList = new ArrayList<String>();
>     for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
>
>         Date dateParsed = sdf.parse(date);
>         dateParsed.setDate(dateParsed.getDate() - i);
>         dateList.add(sdf.format(dateParsed));
>     }
>     Set<String> values2= new HashSet<String>();
>
>     for (String str : dateList) {
>         BasicDBObject find1 = new BasicDBObject("_ky", str);
>         DBObject values1= someDB.findOne(find1);
>
>
>         Iterator iter =  values1.iterator(); /*giving error the method not found (becasue values1 is a dbObject)*/
>
>         while (iter.hasNext()) {
>             values2.add(//???//);
>
>         }
>
>     }
> ```

Any help on how can I iterate the `DBObject`- `values1` and add those values in a `set`- `values2` would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `values1.keySet()` and iterate over that and `get()` any values or use `values1.toMap()` and iterate that `Map` like you would any other.

Comment: Thank you so much evanchooly, can you please show me some examples just in case to see if I am understanding it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The primary abstraction in the Mongo Java Driver is the DBObject which acts like a wrapper around Java's Map<String,Object>.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBList;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;

public class DBObjectKeySetDemo {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        DBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject( "firstName", "Robert" ).append( "lastName", "Kuhar" );
        dbo.put( "age", 49 );
        dbo.put( "hobbies", Arrays.asList( "Fly Fishing", "Board Games", "Roller Derby" ) );

        DBObject browser = new BasicDBObject( "implementation", "Chrome" );
        browser.put( "vendor", "Google" );
        BasicDBList bookmarks = new BasicDBList();
        bookmarks.add( new BasicDBObject( "name", "StackOverflow" ).append( "URL", "http://stackoverflow.com" ) );
        bookmarks.add( new BasicDBObject( "name", "MMS" ).append( "URL", "https://mms.mongodb.com" ) );
        browser.put( "bookmarks", bookmarks );
        dbo.put( "browser", browser );

        for ( String key : dbo.keySet() ) {
            System.out.println( "key: " + key + " value: " + dbo.get( key ) );
        }

        System.out.println( "dbo: " + dbo );
    }
}
```

The "gotcha" is that you can only work directly with "top level" element.  For example, in the above example, through the Java API, you have no way to directly reference "browser.vendor".  Through the Java API you would have to first get the "browser" sub-document, and then get the "vendor" field.

Clear?  As mud?  It helped me to just think of the abstraction as a Map<String,Object> where Object, in the case of a sub-document, may itself be a Map<String,Object>.